# python3 TensorFlow Check failed: new_num_elements == NumElements() (96 vs. 60000)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm coding up a basic Neural Network using TensorFlow(1.12.0) in Python(3.6.7).

Everything seems to work fine individually but I'm getting this error message when I run the `model()`.

```
F ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:663] Check failed: new_num_elements == NumElements() (96 vs. 60000)
Aborted
```

I haven't used the number 96 anywhere in my code as far as I can tell.

I've provided my code below:

model.py:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from preprocessing import getDataset
from parameter import initializeParameters
from forward import forwardPropagation
from cost import computeCost

def model(numberOfIterations = 10000):

    """
        Architecture:
                                        W1, b1                       W2, b2                      W3, b3                      W4, b4
        X(numberOfFeatures, numberOfImages) ---> L1(25, numberOfImages) ---> L2(25, numberOfImages) ---> L3(10, numberOfImages) ---> H(10,numberOFImages)
                                            relu                        relu                        relu                        sigmoid

        W1(25, numberOfFeatures)
        b1(25,1)
        W2(25, 25)
        b2(25, 1)
        W3(10, 25)
        b3(10, 1)
        W4(10, 10)
        b4(10, 1)

    """


    # get all dataset information
    data = getDataset()
    (numberOfFeatures, numberOfImages) = data["X_train"].get_shape()

    # initalize parameters whilst breaking symmetry
    parameters = initializeParameters(numberOfFeatures, numberOfImages)

    # construct forward propagation graph
    (hypothesis, Z4) = forwardPropagation(data["X_train"], parameters)

    # define cost tensor
    cost = computeCost(Z4, data["Y_train"])

    # create optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    # define session object
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)

        # train network
        for iteration in range(numberOfIterations):
            sess.run(optimizer)

            if iteration % 10 == 0:
                print("After iteration", iteration, "cost =", sess.run(cost))


model(numberOfIterations = 50)
```

preprocessing.py:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def getDataset(datasetInfo = True, exampleImage = False):

    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

    numberOfImages_train = np.shape(x_train)[0]
    numberOfImages_test  = np.shape(x_test)[0]

    imageDimension = (np.shape(x_train)[1], np.shape(x_train)[2])

    if datasetInfo:
        print("Number of training data images:", numberOfImages_train)
        print("Number of testing data images:", numberOfImages_test)
        print("Image dimensions:", imageDimension)

#    if exampleImage:
#        randIndex = np.random.randint(0, numberOfImages)
#        plt.imshow(X_mat[:,:,:, randIndex])


    data = {
        "X_train": tf.convert_to_tensor(np.reshape(x_train, (numberOfImages_train, -1)).T, dtype = tf.float64),
       "Y_train": tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train.T),
        "X_test": tf.convert_to_tensor(np.reshape(x_test, (numberOfImages_test, -1)).T, dtype = tf.float64),
        "Y_test": tf.convert_to_tensor(y_test.T)
    }

    return data
```

parameter.py:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def initializeParameters(numberOfFeatures, numberOfImages):

    W1 = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(25, numberOfFeatures) )
    b1 = tf.Variable(np.zeros((25,1)))
    W2 = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(25, 25))
    b2 = tf.Variable(np.zeros((25,1)))
    W3 = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(10, 25))
    b3 = tf.Variable(np.zeros((10,1)))
    W4 = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(10, 10))
    b4 = tf.Variable(np.zeros((10,1)))

    parameters = {
        "W1": W1,
        "b1": b1,
        "W2": W2,
        "b2": b2,
        "W3": W3,
        "b3": b3,
        "W4": W4,
        "b4": b4
    }

    return parameters
```

forward.py:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def forwardPropagation(X, parameters):

    Z1 = tf.add( tf.matmul(parameters["W1"], X) , parameters["b1"])
    A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)

    Z2 = tf.add( tf.matmul(parameters["W2"],A1) , parameters["b2"])
    A2 = tf.nn.relu(Z2)

    Z3 = tf.add( tf.matmul(parameters["W3"],A2) , parameters["b3"])
    A3 = tf.nn.relu(Z3)

    Z4 = tf.add( tf.matmul(parameters["W4"],A3) , parameters["b4"])
    hypothesis = tf.sigmoid(Z4)

    return (hypothesis, Z4)
```

cost.py:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def computeCost(hypothesis, labels):

    onehotlabels = tf.cast(tf.one_hot(labels, depth = 10, axis = 0), tf.float64)

    losses = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = onehotlabels, logits = hypothesis)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(losses)

    return cost
```

Full output:

```
Number of training data images: 60000
Number of testing data images: 10000
Image dimensions: (28, 28)
2018-12-03 12:35:50.912208: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-12-03 12:35:51.221523: F ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:663] Check failed: new_num_elements == NumElements() (96 vs. 60000)
Aborted
```

Answer (score 1):

You are feeding  batch size of 60,000, which is very huge. I reproduced the error  and the error goes away when I limit number training images to 255. But more generally you can feed small batch at at time. Tensorflow has very rich classes and method to handle such kind of issues.

Make the following changes to your methods.
Return just numpy arrays from getDataset() method

```
def getDataset(datasetInfo = True, exampleImage = False):
    # body of the method
    data = {
        "X_train": np.reshape(x_train, (numberOfImages_train, -1)).astype(np.float64),
       "Y_train": y_train,
        "X_test": np.reshape(x_test, (numberOfImages_test, -1)).astype(np.float64),
        "Y_test": y_test
    }
    return data
```

Inside model method make the following changes

```
# Just to match the shape of X_train returned from getDataset method
(numberOfImages , numberOfFeatures ) = data["X_train"].shape
# Create iterator that gives you batch size of sample for at each batch for both training and test cases
train_data =  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data["X_train"],data["Y_train"])).repeat().batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_data =  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data["X_test"],data["Y_test"])).repeat().batch(BATCH_SIZE)

train_itr = train_data.make_one_shot_iterator()
x_train, y_train = train_itr.get_next()
x_train = tf.transpose(x_train)
```

Now feed these x_train and y_train for to build the network.

```
# initalize parameters whilst breaking symmetry
parameters = initializeParameters(numberOfFeatures, numberOfImages)

# construct forward propagation graph
(hypothesis, Z4) = forwardPropagation(x_train, parameters)

# define cost tensor
cost = computeCost(Z4, y_train)
```

I've provided the full code below for both `getDataset` and `model` methods

```
def getDataset(datasetInfo = True, exampleImage = False):

    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

    numberOfImages_train = np.shape(x_train)[0]
    numberOfImages_test  = np.shape(x_test)[0]

    imageDimension = (np.shape(x_train)[1], np.shape(x_train)[2])

    if datasetInfo:
        print("Number of training data images:", numberOfImages_train)
        print("Number of testing data images:", numberOfImages_test)
        print("Image dimensions:", imageDimension)

#    if exampleImage:
#        randIndex = np.random.randint(0, numberOfImages)
#        plt.imshow(X_mat[:,:,:, randIndex])


    data = {
        "X_train": np.reshape(x_train, (numberOfImages_train, -1)).astype(np.float64),
       "Y_train": y_train,
        "X_test": np.reshape(x_test, (numberOfImages_test, -1)).astype(np.float64),
        "Y_test": y_test
    }

    return data
def model(numberOfIterations = 10000, BATCH_SIZE=32):

    """
        Architecture:
                                        W1, b1                       W2, b2                      W3, b3                      W4, b4
        X(numberOfFeatures, numberOfImages) ---> L1(25, numberOfImages) ---> L2(25, numberOfImages) ---> L3(10, numberOfImages) ---> H(10,numberOFImages)
                                            relu                        relu                        relu                        sigmoid

        W1(25, numberOfFeatures)
        b1(25,1)
        W2(25, 25)
        b2(25, 1)
        W3(10, 25)
        b3(10, 1)
        W4(10, 10)
        b4(10, 1)

    """


    # get all dataset information
    data = getDataset()
    (numberOfImages , numberOfFeatures ) = data["X_train"].shape
    train_data =  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data["X_train"],data["Y_train"])).repeat().batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    test_data =  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data["X_test"],data["Y_test"])).repeat().batch(BATCH_SIZE)

    train_itr = train_data.make_one_shot_iterator()
    x_train, y_train = train_itr.get_next()
    x_train = tf.transpose(x_train)

    # initalize parameters whilst breaking symmetry
    parameters = initializeParameters(numberOfFeatures, numberOfImages)

    # construct forward propagation graph
    (hypothesis, Z4) = forwardPropagation(x_train, parameters)

    # define cost tensor
    cost = computeCost(Z4, y_train)

    # create optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    # define session object
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)

        # train network
        for iteration in range(numberOfIterations):
            sess.run(optimizer)

            if iteration % 10 == 0:
                print("After iteration", iteration, "cost =", sess.run(cost))


model(numberOfIterations = 50)
```

Comment: I'm still getting some dimension mismatch errors. I don't quite understand what's happening in these lines:
______________________________

train_data =  tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data["X_train"],data["Y_train"])).repeat().batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data["X_test"],data["Y_test"])).repeat().batch(BATCH_SIZE)

train_itr = train_data.make_one_shot_iterator()
x_train, y_train = train_itr.get_next()
x_train = tf.transpose(x_train)
________________________
Please explain

Comment: that is: repeat training data num_epochs times, then slice into batches of BATCH_SIZE